# Trouble using lambda function within my scraper

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, web-scraping

I've written a script to parse the name and price of certain items from craigslist. The `xpath` I've defined within my scraper are working ones. The thing is when I try to scrape the items in usual way then applying `try/except` block I can avoid `IndexError` when the value of certain price is none. I even tried with customized function to make it work and found success as well.

However, In this below snippet I would like to apply `lambda` function to kick out `IndexError` error. I tried but could not succeed.

Btw, when I run the code It neither fetches anything nor throws any error either.

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

page = requests.get('http://bangalore.craigslist.co.in/search/rea?s=120').text
tree = fromstring(page)

# I wish to fix this function to make a go
get_val = lambda item,path:item.text if item.xpath(path) else ""

for item in tree.xpath('//li[@class="result-row"]'):
    link = get_val(item,'.//a[contains(@class,"hdrlnk")]')
    price = get_val(item,'.//span[@class="result-price"]')
    print(link,price)
```

Comment: Don't use a `lambda` expression to define a named function; just use a `def` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your lambda function `get_val` returns the text of the item if the path exists, and not the text of the searched node. This is probably not what you want. If want want to return the text content of the (first) element matching the path, you should write:

```
get_val = lambda item, path: item.xpath(path)[0].text if item.xpath(path) else ""
```

Please note that `xpath` returns a list. I assume here that you have only one element in that list.

The output is something like that:

```
...
Residential Plot @ Sarjapur Check Post ₨1000
Prestige dolce vita apartments in whitefield, Bangalore 
Brigade Golden Triangle, ₨12500000
Nikoo Homes, ₨6900000
```

But I think you want a link, not the text. If this is the case, read below.

Ok, how to get a link? When you have an anchor `a`, you get its `href` (the link) in the table of attibutes: `a.attrib["href"]`.

So as I understand, in the case of the price, you want the text, but in the case of the anchor, you want the value of one specific attributes, href. Here's the real use of lambdas. Rewrite your function like that:

```
def get_val(item, path, l):
    return l(item.xpath(path)[0]) if item.xpath(path) else ""
```

The parameter `l` is a function that is applied to the node. `l` may return the text of the node, or the href of an anchor:

```
link = get_val(item,'.//a[contains(@class,"hdrlnk")]', lambda n: n.attrib["href"])
price = get_val(item,'.//span[@class="result-price"]', lambda n: n.text)
```

Now the output is:

```
...
https://bangalore.craigslist.co.in/reb/d/residential-plot-sarjapur/6522786441.html ₨1000
https://bangalore.craigslist.co.in/reb/d/prestige-dolce-vita/6522754197.html 
https://bangalore.craigslist.co.in/reb/d/brigade-golden-triangle/6522687904.html ₨12500000
https://bangalore.craigslist.co.in/reb/d/nikoo-homes/6522687772.html ₨6900000
```